# How do I set logfile rotation limit for CF8 -out logs?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to set the number of logs to keep for the CF -out logs. I found a jrunsvc command line switch to set this but it throws an error saying the value must be at least 1000:
jrunsvc.exe -logfileRotationLimit 50 "ColdFusion 8 Application Server"
Error: log file rotaion limit must be at least 1000

The default is 200 files which seems excessive but 1000 is even worse. Am I not understanding this value properly? I did set it to 1001 and then I found this registry entry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ColdFusion 9 Application Server\LogFileRotationLimit

I'm hesitant to set it there manually in case the value does not equal the number of files to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

melikeum, like you, I've not understood that error either. It seems clearly a bug.

But yes, the easy workaround is to modify that registry key value. I've done it successfully, and yes, you can set it lower then.

Note as well that you can also set LogFileSize as a value there. That's useful to increase the size, for instance, so that the files are larger and hold more information (useful during diagnostic analysis).

For any later readers of this, note that when you create the key value(s), you'd use Edit>New>String Value (in Regedit). Note that this works for CF8 as well (with a correspondingly changed keyname of \ColdFusion 8 Application Server.) I'm even pretty sure it would work on CF7 as well (\ColdFusion MX 7 Application Server).